# Is it possible to message a company MS Teams user from a private Home Skype account?

Tags: skype, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to message a company MS Teams user from a private Home Skype account?

Can you download teams free version and create a fake organization and message other team users in other companies or simply use free version of teams with private Outlook account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported and we have no current plans to do so. If it were possible, it would be a great way to send spam messages to Teams users which is fortunately not a problem.